# How can I specify the template for a silverlight datagrid column?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that has AutoGenerateColumns="True".  I'm binding that DataGrid to a collection of objects that are of an unknown datatype at design time.

The DataGrid is able to identify the data type that a particular column is bound to.  It shows a textblock or a checkbox if the content is text or a bool respectively.

I want to show data in a particular way (i.e. a DataTemplate) if it's of a specific type.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you know how many columns you need? Disregarding the DataType?

Comment: No,  I may bind to an object that has 8 properties or one that has 25.  All different datatypes for the properties.  If a datatype is a "RickLinkAction", I'd like to display a LinkButton.  If it's a String, I'll want to display a TextBlock.  If it's a "RickCalendarAction" I'll want to display something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are unaware of the columns which may exist you have to revert to code behind. If you had known that you will always have 8 properties on the given object along with there types; you could move this behavior into the XAML and not have to deal with the handling of the event.

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28VS.95%29.aspx) reference sums up how to accomplish this but it boils down to handling the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event.

```
private void dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{

     ...

}
```

Comment: I tried that and it's not working for me.  The type that my datagrid is bound to is a type that is dynamically created at run time...So my dataGrid can't specify the property name...

Comment: The event handling is not working or the fact that using pure XAML is not working?